# redirect route to another

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am trying to redirect route to another before route callback is executed. I have following piece of code:

```
console.log("file loaded");
(function (History) {
    var _navigate = History.prototype.navigate;

    _.extend(History.prototype, {
        navigate: function (fragment, opts) {
            alert("adad");
            return _navigate.call(this, fragment, opts);
        }
    });
})(Backbone.History);
```

This code wraps `Backbone.History.navigate` method, and showing alert on the method call. But this alert never shows up when I am changing routes.

The `console.log` line is just to be sure that file has been loaded after backbone.js.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I assume you've called Backbone.history.start() somewhere?

Comment: yes I did - my views are changing, I have no idea why this doesnt work

Comment: It must be something else. I just plugged your code into a Backbone project I've got open, and I was instantly annoyed by the `adad` alert as soon as I navigated.  :) I've got the boilerplate code anchor tag to "Navigate" code plugged into my app, which may change the behavior.

Comment: Backbone 0.9.10. Browsers = IE9 and Chrome current both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overriding the wrong thing: that `navigate` isn't used the way you think it is.

Let us look at part of [`Backbone.history.start`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1078):

```
// Start the hash change handling, returning `true` if the current URL matches
// an existing route, and `false` otherwise.
start: function(options) {
  //...
  if (this._hasPushState) {
    Backbone.$(window).on('popstate', this.checkUrl);
  } else if (this._wantsHashChange && ('onhashchange' in window) && !oldIE) {
    Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl);
  } else if (this._wantsHashChange) {
    this._checkUrlInterval = setInterval(this.checkUrl, this.interval);
  }
```

You'll see that all the various ways of handling routing in Backbone go through `checkUrl` rather than `navigate`. The `checkUrl` method does a bit of busy work and calls `loadUrl`; one [part of the busy work is this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1157):

```
  if (this.iframe) this.navigate(current);
```

so `navigate` will be called but only when an `<iframe>` is being used to simulate `hashchange` and `popstate` events and AFAIK that only happens when you're using an older version of IE.

Back to the usual path through the code. We've seen that `checkUrl` does some busy work and calls `loadUrl` so what does that do? [`loadUrl` does this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1164):

```
loadUrl: function(fragmentOverride) {
  var fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragmentOverride);
  var matched = _.any(this.handlers, function(handler) {
    if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
      handler.callback(fragment);
      return true;
    }
  });
  return matched;
}
```

If you look at the [`route` method in `History`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1145) and the [`route` method in `Route`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L966) you'll see that `handler.callback` is what calls the route handler from one of your routers and triggers the routing event.

The `navigate` method that you're replacing is pretty much only used by [`Router`'s `navigate`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L980):

```
navigate: function(fragment, options) {
  Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
  return this;
}
```

If you want to redirect before the route handler is called, you could replace `loadUrl` with something like this:

```
(function(History) {
    var _loadUrl = History.prototype.loadUrl;
    _.extend(History.prototype, {
        loadUrl: function() {
            var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
            args[0] = this.getFragment(args[0]);
            // If args[0] is the fragment that you want to
            // redirect then replace it here or do whatever
            // needs to be done.
            return _loadUrl.apply(this, args);
        }
    });
})(Backbone.History);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/e4KYK/

Overall I think you'd be better off handling the redirect in a normal route handler: when the offending route is called, just call [`navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) on whatever router is handy.

---

Keep in mind that `Backbone.History` isn't documented beyond the [`start` method](http://backbonejs.org/#History) so everything here is subject to change.